# ImportError: The Python module 'xapian_backend' has no 'XapianEngine' class

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, xapian

I upgraded Django from 1.5 to 1.7 with django-haystack `django-haystack==2.0.0` and xapian `xapian-haystack==1.1.5b0` getting an error.

```
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685396 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 198, in send
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685469 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]     response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685481 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/__init__.py", line 59, in reset_search_queries
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685520 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]     for conn in connections.all():
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685530 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 112, in all
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685597 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]     return [self[alias] for alias in self.connections_info]
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685608 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 100, in __getitem__
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685634 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]     self._connections[key] = load_backend(self.connections_info[key]['ENGINE'])(using=key)
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685644 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 53, in load_backend
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685657 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]     return import_class(full_backend_path)
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685666 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 23, in import_class
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685679 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439]     raise ImportError("The Python module '%s' has no '%s' class." % (module_path, class_name))
[Mon Nov 16 13:32:48.685695 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 692193:tid 139901570070272] [remote 127.0.0.1:25439] ImportError: The Python module 'xapian_backend' has no 'XapianEngine' class.
```

**UPDATE**
I've tried to switch to `whoosh` instead of xapian but the error persists.

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'xapian_backend.XapianEngine',
        'PATH': '/home/kbuzz/whoosh_index',
    },
}
```

Comment: If you want to change to whoosh; you should definitly change the engine too not just the path

Comment: @bigOTHER thanks I've done this